# How do you interpret the results from shootout.alioth.debian.org?

Tags: language-agnostic, benchmarking

A lot of people talk about the performance comparison of some languages by referring to the tests on shootout.alioth.debian.org . The thing is, I don't know how to read the results. The image seems incomprehensible, as I can't seem to find a **NORMAL** legend. Can you explain one of the tests, with a image? Choose whatever languages you want.

Comment: Which "image"? Link to an example - there's a lot of information shown at shootout.alioth.debian.org so you need to be specific.

Comment: each language comparison benchmarks produces an image, along with the test results table

Comment: Be specific! This? http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=nbody&lang=all This? http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/fulldata.php?test=nbody&p1=gpp-4&p2=ruby-2&p3=gpp-4&p4=ruby-2 This? http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/csharp.php

Answer (score 3):

All results are ratios between the speed / memory usage / source code size of the given programs in the two chosen languages.

Take [Perl vs. Ruby](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=perl&lang2=ruby&box=1), for example. Every benchmark is expressed in a ratio **Perl / Ruby**. For the mandelbrot program, the Perl implementation completed 8 times faster than the Ruby implementation. The result therefore is **1/8**. This is then marked in the graph at the 1/8 point. The memory usage is actually better in Ruby, with a factor of 191.

The result of this is that the line marked by **1** indicates that the two chosen languages are *equal* in performance / memory usage / source code size, with the given implementations. Every value **below 1 (downwards)** means that the *first* mentioned language is faster / consumes less memory / is smaller. Everything **above 1 (upwards)** means that the *latter* language is faster, etc.

The vertical scale is logarithmic, meaning that small bars mean *little difference*, while long bars mean *enormous difference*.

All the vertical bars per measurement unit represent all the benchmarks that exist for this comparison, ordered from good to bad.

I hope this helps.